# Generating elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i wonder if below, generating content the jQuery 1.4 way

```
$("<div />", {
  "class": "loading",
  "html": "some html code here"
}).appendTo("#elem");
```

or the normal "easy" way is better. any performance or benefits from either?

```
$("#elem").append("some html code here");
```

oh i just thought of 1 benefit of the 1st, i can add event handlers. is this the only benefit?

```
var a = $("<a />", { href: "#", click: function() {}, text: "link text"});
```

on a side note, if i want to add the above link in the middle of some content i will do ...

```
var a = $("<a />", { href: "#", click: function() {}, text: "link text"});
var div = $("<div />", { html: "here is some content " + a.html() + " here is more html" });
```

right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add like `anything` in the `1.4.x` way:

```
$('<div/>', {
     'class:'    'someclass',
     css:        {
          width: '200px',
          height:'200px'
     },
     click:      function(e){
          alert($(this).data('mydata'));
     },
     data:       {
          mydata: 'Yay!'
     }
});
```

As for performance, I didn't benchmark it yet but I can hardly believe that this is much slower than doing

```
$('<div></div>').click(function(){}) // etc.
```

Depending on the markup you want to add dynamically, it can really be faster to concatenate `string literals` and append one chunk of `html markup` once.
In that scenario you would need to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` handlers to have `event handlers`.

Maybe I misunderstand your goal in your approach at the end. Why would you construct an element with `jQuery` along with an `event handler` to lose all that information by putting just the `html` string into that div?

You should use `.append()` or `.appendTo()` here instead.

```
var a = $("<a />", { href: "#", click: function() {}, text: "link text"});
var div = $("<div />").append(a);
```